# LNK2005 Error when using Constant Memory in CUDA Header (.cuh) File

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a CUDA Header (.cuh) file that contains two constant float arrays. There are two files that include this header, one is a CPP file that tries to copy to this constant memory and one is a CUDA file that tries to use this constant memory. All three files are in a project that should compile to make a DLL.

I've tried to simplify things with the following code:

obj1.cuh

```
#pragma once

__constant__ float d_array1[5];
__constant__ float d_array2[5];
```

obj1.cu

```
#include "obj1.cuh"

//do random stuff
__global__ void kernel(float * d_array1, float * d_array2) {
  int id = threadIdx.x;
  float sum = d_array1[i] + d_array2[i];
}
```

ext.cpp

```
#include "obj1.cuh"

void function(float * array1, float * array2) {
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_array1, array1, sizeof(float)*5);
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_array2, array2, sizeof(float)*5);

  kernel<<<1,5>>>(d_array1,d_array2);
}
```

The build fails and outputs the following errors:

```
1>ext.obj : error LNK2005: "float * d_array1" (?d_array1@@3PAMA) already defined in obj1.cu.obj
1>ext.obj : error LNK2005: "float * d_array2" (?d_array2@@3PAMA) already defined in obj1.cu.obj
```

Before you ask, yes I have tried using include guards instead of the pragma once and it still outputs the same error.

Include guard version of obj1.cuh

```
#ifndef CONSTANTARRAYS
#define CONSTANTARRAYS
__constant__ float d_array1[5];
__constant__ float d_array2[5];
#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the linker tells you: The variables are *defined* in multiple [*translation units*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29).

When the preprocessor includes a header files, it quite literally pastes the text in the header into the place where the `#include` directive was, which means both generated objects files will have the definitions of the variables.

What you should do is to only *declare* the variables in the header file, then in a single source file you *define* them. To change the definition to a declaration, the simplest way is to prepend the `extern` keyword:

```
#pragma once

extern __constant__ float d_array1[5];
extern __constant__ float d_array2[5];
```

Then in a single source file you have the old definitions:

```
__constant__ float d_array1[5];
__constant__ float d_array2[5];
```

The `#pragma once` or header include guards prevents a header file to be included multiple times in the same translation unit.

Comment: Thank you Joachim. What I don't understand though is that when I only define the two arrays in the .cu file, how is the .cpp file able to use the array when it's not defined in that file? For example I can use the arrays in the cudaMemcpyToSymbol function without an error.

Comment: @JonnyPringle That's what the *declarations* in the header file is for.